# We should react on [reactive-mongo-java]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[reactive-mongo-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactive-mongo-java) is just a combination of existing tags and doesn't have any value.

Which is mirrored by it having only 20 uses and no wiki.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/reactive-streams/

Comment: @HansPassant while in theory it could refer to this and then it would be a valid tag it doesn't seem to be used in this way.

Comment: If they *are* about the link @HansPassant provided, [[tag:reactive-mongodb-java]] is an odd choice. [[tag:mongodb-java-reactive-streams]] would seem better, or the tags [[tag:java-reactive-streams]] and [[tag:mongodb]] (note I know nothing about Java, and if there are other reactive streams so the latter could be very incorrect).